# CUDA concurrent kernel execution behavior and efficency

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, cuda

I don't have a CUDA card yet, and I have to focus on OpenCL now. So... I think I better just ask..

**1. Are kernels executed in the order I invoke them?**

If I invoke A through stream 0, B through stream 1, C through stream 0, D through stream1, E through stream 0, is it ensured that the device sees the kernels in the order A, B, C, D, E?

If I invoke kernels A and B through stream 0, and then invoker C through stream 1, will B block C？Do I have to invoke them in an order A, C, B to allow C running concurrently with A and B?

**2. Are there any stalls or penalties if I want kernels to run concurrently?**

On AMD cards, inter-queue dependency seems to be very expensive (I may wrong. Actually I hope that I'm wrong. But just no one can tell me weither I'm right or not yet.) 
If I have kernels A, B, and C, while A and B are independent and C depends on A and B. On AMD cards, there will be a huge delay if I let D wait on A or B, which make synchronized execution much faster for almost all situations.

What I now understand is that a CUDA card only have one queue for computation. That is I can express dependency with the order I invoke kernels instead of events as on AMD cards. Will it be more efficent or even penalty free?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the command queue you created. If it is an in-order queue then they are executed in order, in the order you submitted them. If it is an out-of-order queue then the runtime *might* execute them out of order and perhaps even concurrently. It does not have to. Some devices or drivers don't support out-of-order queues and just treat them as in-order.

Managing an out-of-order command queue moves the dependency burden on the host application; you need to use event objects to build a dependency graph.

Another (I think easier) way to get concurrent execution is to use multiple (likely in-order) command queues. Put independent work in each, and the runtime is allowed to run kernels (one from each) concurrently. It doesn't have to, but if it can, it should.

Comment: Um... is this about CUDA

Comment: Nope, it's about OpenCL. The question had an OpenCL tag, and I saw it there and didn't realize it was about CUDA. If you only want to know about CUDA, maybe don't add OpenCL tags. Some of it likely applies to CUDA so I'll leave it here.

Comment: Actually CUDA is quite different from OpenCL. It apears that it has only one command queue that supports concurrent execution while the kernels are still dispatched in order. I will get my card today anyway, I can look into it myself soon...

Answer (score 0):

1. On newer devices kernels from different stream will be executed out-of-order. I behavior I described in the question would only happen in very old architectures.
2. A kernel will start executing as soon as possible. Invoking A and B in different streams with B waiting on A doesn't have any obvious difference from Invoking A and B in order in a same stream.